# php scrape a site after login

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I want to scrape a site after login but unable to do so, my chrome developer tool is giving me following data to make curl

```
Request URL:http://example.com/ab/index.php/company
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:x.x.x.x:80

Request Headers
 Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:120
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:PHPSESSID=d2mnsm293nhadmmtoananmaa; abc_fd_test=3fdb2f2be5acda39ae4aa7679f224466
Host:example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/ab/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/x.x.x.x Safari/537.36

Form Data

abc_fd_test:3fdb2f2be5acda39ae4aa7679f224466
email:abc@abc.com
password:xxxxxx
btnLogin:Sign in
```

and my code for curl is below

```
 <?php
 $url="http://example.com/ab/index.php/company";

 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('email' =>   'abc@abc.com', 'password' => 'xxxxxx')));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://example.com/ab/");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 var_dump($data);

?>
```

One point which i notice that above code is making GET request instead of POST. Please help if any thing is required to add in it. The form is also posting a hidden field abc_fd_test which change each time when form load.

Comment: @Key Y-N I tried that as well but still my curl is send GET request instead of POST and also I dont know how to set  abc_fd_test and post it